# @FormParam truncated for embedded &apos; in content Apache Wink

Tags: escaping, apache-wink, form-parameter

I admit we are doing something silly by using a url encoded form to send an XML document in a single variable (linefeeds converted to spaces, and content escaped), but this is to accommodate a client that can only send form data.

When one of the strings in the escaped XML content contained an apostrophe

```
&apos;
```

the parsing of the request body stops and does not return the remainder of the variable.  Of course, this creates a problem because the XML document we retrieve is incomplete.

What is the proper way to pass an apostrophe in a form parameter when the receiver is using the Apache Wink JAX-RS libraries?

A line like this:

```
        <decisionspace  title="Traffic Study" details="Discuss the Rivertowns Square projects impact on traffic" />
```

works fine, but a line like this:

```
        <decisionspace  title="Traffic Study" details="Discuss the Rivertowns Square project&apos;s impact on traffic" />
```

is truncated after "Square project"

The characters being escaped are:

```
"&" becomes "&amp;"
"\"" (double quote) becomes "&quot;"
"'" (single quote) becomes "&apos;"
"<" becomes "&lt;"
">" becomes "&gt;"
bytes < 0x20 or > 0x7f" become "&#nnn;"
```

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more digging, it appears that the form parameters are stored in a MultivaluedMap (formParameters) and, the ampersand was interpreted as a value separator (as in a query string) so the call to formParameters.get(getName()) only returns up to that position (displaying the formParameter value shows the mulitple values separated by commas in the toString()).  I suspect when the request body was interpreted to fill the formParameter map, it parsed the value as a query string and separating the content at each ampersand.

I'm certain with a different escape mechanism so the ampersand is a %26 or something so it takes the entire line as a single string that I'll be all set.

I guess it all depends on the perspective of the parser in any given context and for form params it is thinking query string formatting (of course).

Comment: In retrospect, the MediaType application/x-www-form-urlencoded should have provided the clue...

Comment: Using URLEncoder.encode(requestValue,"UTF-8") at the client, and URLDecoder.decode(formParamValue,"UTF-8") at the server did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Form parameters are separated using `&`. You should escape the content in the same way you do it for URLs and not for XML/HTML.